# Regex, how to selecct //+ without ://

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var test = https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e
console.log(test.replace(/[\/{2,}]+/g,'/'));
```

I want to replace all **//+** to single **/**, but **https://** shouldn't be changed.

I tried with

> (!:)[[/{2,}]+

but it doesn't work.

How can I replace all //+ to single / except https:// ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of `replace` [replacement callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) which arguments are as follows:

1. **match:** The matched substring. (Corresponds to $& above.)
2. **p1, p2, pN:** (Corresponds to $1, $2, etc. above.)
3. **offset**: The offset of the matched substring within the whole string being examined
4. **string**: The whole string

We only capture consecutives `/` that are not preceded by http/s. Since `https://` is matched by `(?:https?:\/\/)` but we discard that capture group using `?:` that group won't appear as the `capture` argument in the callback function. Now the `capture` argument only contains the last part of the regex: `(\/+)` which we now replace by a single `/`

```js
let test = 'https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e';
const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)|(\/+)/g;
test = test.replace(regex, (match, capture) =>  capture ? '/' : match);

console.log(test);
```

**ES2018 Answer**

[RegExp Lookbehind Assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) made it into ES2018, so the following regex will do:

```
const test = 'https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e';
test.replace(/(?<!https?:)\/+/g, '/');
```

- Check the following [link](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions) for support in node.
- Lookbehind was shipped in [Chrome 62](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545&desc=2).

Answer (score 2):

We would really like to replace the following pattern with a single forward slash:

```
(?<!https?:)\/+
```

In other words, do a lookbehind and make sure that we are not replacing the `http` protocol slashes.  But JavaScript's `replace` does not support lookbehinds.  As an alternative, can first do a blanket replacement of `//` to just `/`.  Then, replace `http:/` or `https:/` with a double slash.

Try this option:

```js
var test = "https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e";
test = test.replace(/\/+/g, '/');
test = test.replace(/(https?:)\//g, '$1//');

console.log(test);
```

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Why would you ever expect more than two contiguous forward slashes in a URL?

Comment: I don't, but check the OP example, it does have 3. `//test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Good points.  I came up with a workaround, which is to do a blanket replacement of any number of forward slashes with a single slash, and then to do a cleanup replacement of the protocol afterwards.

Comment: That's a good workaround, I still prefer my answer though, since It's only one `replace` call.

Comment: Yeah, I can see you know your way around the JS regex API.  Actually, the standard way of doing this might be what I first suggested, namely using a negative lookbehind, but it's not supported.

Comment: Yeah, the lookbehind is the way to go, luckily for me they're supported in node 8 with `--harmony` flag

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var test = 'https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e';
console.log(test.replace(/(https:\/\/)?([^\/]*)\/+/g,'$1$2/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = "https://test.com///?abc=def//&test=1e"
test = test.replace(/(^https?:\/)?\/+/g,'$1/')
console.log(test); // https://test.com/?abc=def/&test=1e
```